# Parsing a class in BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Basically I would like to access the elements inside an html table.

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3Aibm&ei=Hz4oVZq-PISjiQKYu4GoAQ')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

td = soup.find_all('td', class_='ctsymbol')
```

I get a whole nothing...[]

I tried this approach on the same td but this time on a local text file and that seems to work fine. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also tried soup.findAll('td',{'class':'ctsymbol'}):

Comment: Why do you expect the `ctsymbol` class to be there? Take into account that your *browser* can execute JavaScript code after loading a page, not everything you see in the developer tool is *actually in the HTML source*.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no such element in the page:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3Aibm&ei=Hz4oVZq-PISjiQKYu4GoAQ')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> {c for e in soup.find_all('td') if 'class' in e.attrs for c in e['class']}
set(['name', 'val', 'p', 'i', 'period', 'itxt', 'lft', 't', 'key', 'colHeader', 'linkbtn'])
```

That's the set of all classes uses on `<td>` elements in the HTML served. Take into account you cannot rely on the element tree you find in your browser development tools, as they reflect the page *after JavaScript code has run*.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the advise. Which begs the question, how do you get those elements then?Do any of the python modules have the ability to invoke the browser and then one can parse the html? I actually found this is a dupe of 23282182, where they use the selenium packge.

Comment: @rearThing: I don't see an easy AJAX request to load instead when looking at that page activity. I don't find the `ctsymbol` class either, though. For a complex page like that, if there are no alternative means to get the information, then running the page under Selenium is the next best option.